# NodeJS Async Operation Not Completing On Initial Execution Before Sync Operation Executes

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous, async-await

I am writing a small NodeJS script which takes a zip file and extracts the contents to a folder.  I then search the extracted zip contents on the file system for a specified file type which is then output to an array.

The issue I am facing is on the initial run of the script, the extraction process does not complete prior to my "findFile" function kicking off.  To resolve this I have attempted to use Async/Await which I was hoping would kick off the "findFile" function upon the successful completion of my unzip/extraction.

**Below is a simplified code example:**

```html
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const unzipper = require('unzipper');
const path = require('path');

    const artifact = 'C:\\PATH\\TO\\MY\\ZIP\\FILE.zip;
    const dir = 'C:\\PATH\\TO\\MY\\EXTRACTED\\ZIP\\FILE\\CONTENTS';

    const findFile = function (dir, pattern) {
        const results = [];
        fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(function (dirInner) {
            dirInner = path.resolve(dir, dirInner);
            const stat = fs.statSync(dirInner);
            if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                results = results.concat(findFile(dirInner, pattern));
            }
            if (stat.isFile() && dirInner.endsWith(pattern)) {
                results.push(dirInner);
            }
        });
        return results
    }

    const readZip = async () => {
        fs.createReadStream(artifact).pipe(unzipper.Extract({path: 'C:\\LOCATION\\WHERE\\EXTRACTED\\ZIP\\WILL\\GO'}))
            await findFile(dir, ".iar");
    }

    readZip()
```

**When running the above initially I get the following:**

"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\PATH\TO\EXTRACTED\ZIP\CONTENTS'"

**However, upon the second run of the code I get the expected results:**

```
[
  'C:\\PATH\\TO\\SOME\\FILE.iar',
  'C:\\PATH\\TO\\SOME\\FILE.iar',
  'C:\\PATH\\TO\\SOME\\FILE.iar'
]
```

This behavior tells me the "findFile" function executes prior to the extraction process completing.  This leads me back to the question:

**Question 1:**
Why is the "findFile" function not using "await" for the extract process to complete before executing?

**Question 2:**
Can anyone provide me with some code examples of how I can make this happen while still utilizing the code I have already written?

I would prefer to not have to rewrite the entirety of this script as I am relatively sure this is a syntactical issue on my part and since I am a newb at this rewriting the entirety of the script would take me quite some time to get completed.  Any and all help is appreciated....

Comment: Side note: `const results = results.concat(findFile(dirInner, pattern));` creates a const within a block that you never use; so you won't see the entries from that call to `findFile`. You probably meant `results = results.concat(findFile(dirInner, pattern));` (no `const` in front of it) or `results.push(...findFile(dirInner, pattern));`

Comment: Yes that is correct...that was me playing around with the function to see (if anything) I could get it to work as I wanted.  I forgot to revert it back.  I have made the correction on the posting....